# How do I find the roots of these quadratic polynomials and what formula or process do I need to use?

Tags: polynomials

Find the roots of the quadratic polynomials: 
\begin{gather}
p_1(x) = 4x^2-7x+3, \\
p_2(x) = x^2-5x-8.
\end{gather}

I have found the roots of the first polynomial however, I am unsure of the second one. When I plugged it into the quadratic formula I got the answer of 
$$ 5 \pm \frac{\sqrt{57}}{2} $$
but I know that the roots aren't going to be in decimal form. Have I calculated wrong or missed a step?

Comment: Have you made any progress finding the roots?

Comment: If the quadratic formula does not quickly come to mind, and no obvious factorization occurs to you, then there is always completing the square.  You may prefer these alternatives in a different order.

Comment: I realized I had made an error in the quadratic formula and that's why my answer for the first one was incorrect. But as for the second one, I've come to the point where I have 5 - or + 57^1/2 / 2 and I am unsure of what the answer will be since the square root of 57 is a decimal. I have to submit this online so I'm worried about formatting.

Comment: Your homework should have specific instructions about formatting. If it doesn't mention *approximating* or *rounding* (usually to a certain number of digits) I would assume they want the exact answer, square roots and all. But again, your homework should have instructions that are far more reliable than anyone here.

Comment: What do you mean "but I know that the roots aren't going to be in decimal form" ???? Your answer isn't in decimal form.  (BTW the answer should be $\frac{5 \pm \sqrt{57}}{2}$, not $5 \pm \frac{ \sqrt{57}}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the website WolfAlpha to help actually graph the function for you and then it can calculate the roots. This website can help check your roots for you!